# Run parametrized task using grunt.task.run(taskname)

Tags: gruntjs

I did stackoverflow search and looked at Grunt API docs but couldn't find a way to run a parametrized task using grunt.task.run(taskname).

I have a simple task which accepts a parameter and prints the message on console:

```
grunt.registerTask('hello', 'greeting task', function(name) {
   if(!name || !name.length)
        grunt.warn('you need to provide a name');

    console.log('hello ' + name + '!');

});
```

I call the above task using below task which validates the task and if task exists then it runs it:

```
 grunt.registerTask('validateandruntask', 'if task available then run given  task', function(taskname) {
       if(!taskname || !taskname.length) {
           grunt.warn('task name is needed to run this task');
       }

    if(!grunt.task.exists(taskname)) {
        grunt.log.writeln('this task does not exist!');
    } else {
        grunt.log.writeln(taskname + ' exists. Going to run this task');
        grunt.task.run(taskname);
    }

});
```

Now from command line, I am passing 'hello' task as parameter to 'validateandruntask' but I am not been able to pass the parameter to 'hello' task from command line:

This is what I tried on command line but it didn't work:

*grunt validateandruntask:hello=foo*

*grunt validateandruntask:hello:param=name*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, the way to pass an arg through the command line is to use `:`.
For example to call `hello` directly:

```
grunt hello:you
```

To call it with multiple arguments, just separate them by `:`, like

```
grunt hello:mister:president
```

And to use these multiple arguments in the task, you do the same as plain Javascript: use `arguments` ([all details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)):

```
grunt.registerTask('hello', 'greeting task', function(name) {
  if(!name || !name.length)
    grunt.warn('you need to provide a name');
  // unfortunately arguments is not an array,
  // we need to convert it to use array methods like join()
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var greet = 'hello ' + args.join(' ') + '!';
  console.log(greet);
});
```

Then you want to call `grunt validateandruntask:hello:mister:president`, and modify your code to handle the variable parameters as well:

```
grunt.registerTask('validateandruntask', 'if task available then run given  task', function(taskname) {
   if(!taskname || !taskname.length) {
       grunt.fail.fatal('task name is needed to run this task');
   }

  var taskToCall = taskname;
  for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    taskToCall += ':' + arguments[i];
  }
  console.log(taskToCall);

  if(!grunt.task.exists(taskname)) {
      grunt.log.writeln('this task does not exist!');
  } else {
      grunt.log.writeln(taskname + ' exists. Going to run this task');
      grunt.task.run(taskToCall);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Xavier! I understand that's one way to achieve what I am looking for but my question is more on how I can call a parametrized task using grunt.task.run? This is more of Grunt API question about grunt.task.run. I couldn't find any documentation about if this is possible? If it's not then I need to stick to passing additional parameters and that would make application code complex because the tasks you want to run using grunt.task.run() may accept n number of parameters.

Comment: The way to pass any number of arguments to grunt.task.run() is by adding them to the task name separated by ':'. And the way to use any number of arguments in a function is through `arguments` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)). I'll update the answer with example.

Comment: This doesn't directly address my question of running task with multiple params with my original code where I was expecting my validateandrun task to be able to run tasks with multiple args without really parsing the arguments object. I wanted grunt.task.run() API to support this implicitly, i.e. run tasks with multiple args but I guess they don't support it. I have an issue/query open on their github repo. But anyway your answer does provide a way to achieve what I am looking for in an alternate way. So I will accept your answer. Thanks!